# How to avoid using same class as Type and Argument

Tags: kotlin

I have a BaseActivity in my project and one of its jobs is to instantiate the Acvities's ViewModels. It goes like this:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<VM : ViewModel>(clazz: KClass<VM>) :
        AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    protected lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    protected val viewModel  by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders
                .of(this, viewModelFactory).get(clazz.java)
    }
}
```

And then MyActivity extends it:

```
class MyActivity : BaseActivity<MyViewModel>(MyViewModel::class) {

    ...

    fun doSomething() {
     viewModel.someMethodSpecifToMyViewModel()
    }
}
```

As you cans see, I need to pass MyViewModel as a class, so I can use it on ViewModelProviders, but I also need to pass it as a Type, so my viewModel is cast to the correct ViewModel and I can use its own methods.

This works fine and all, but it really bothers me that I have to pass MyViewModel two times to my BaseActivity.

Is there any way I can pass only it as a type or class and still get things to work?

Comment: Seems not possible currently, see https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/reified-type-parameters-through-inline-constructors/12537/5